Need help in importing wallets to my phone
I have 3 wallets that are currently on my browser(2 old 1 new). I imported them on my phone but the other wallet (new one) shows as "you are watching this account" which means I can not use it. Any leads on how I can have control this wallet?

I think the new wallet might not share the seed phrase as the old ones, so it's not showing up.
Try exporting the private key and import it using this method.
